# Android - res/values-ja/strings.xml font issue

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

I need to support multiple languages in my native app. I could properly create strings.xml  file in their respective folders for various languages (Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, etc.). However, I have tough time in creating strings.xml under values-ja folder for Japanese language.

I have strings in japanese font in word document. When I copy these strings to strings.xml file in eclipse, the strings are replaced with junk characters (i assume it is due to japanese font missing in eclipse or wrong encoding). I googled for hours but couldn't find a way to fix it.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the strings.xml in UTF-8 format.

Follow [this guide](http://redhotwords.com/unicode.html) in order to save your file as a text file using the right encoding. than you can open it in eclipse or notepad to do the your copy paste

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I verified that the encoding is set to Unicode (UTF-8) in eclipse for the XML file. But pasting text in Japanese font is getting replaced with junk chars. :(

Comment: The problem is in the way word handles characters, not eclipse. you will need to export the word file in UTF-8 encoding, only than you can copy paste the text correctly.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't work. It is weird as all the other languages are working fine, only issue is with the Japanses.

Comment: Paste the words in the xml editor, not in the "friendly editor". It would be better if first you paste the "letters" in another editor such as notepad++.